# How to get to a select element when its hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

Usually when I want to use a select element its pretty simple, I just go:

```
val selectCompany = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#company_id")))
selectCompany.selectByValue("975")
```

But in my case it dosen't work...

this is the html (the relevant part):

[image]

But I get error using the css selector, this is the error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration
>   or timeout: 60 milliseconds

I tried to add Wait element but still not working...

I guess the issue is that the select element is hidden, can someone please helpppp

thanks

Comment: Why not just use normal javascript?

Comment: I dont know how to....you can tell me and I will :) @Manu

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems that the implementation of the dropdown has been changed from a **HTML-select dropdown** to a **div-type**, meaning now probably you would have to click on the element **`<div class="select-upload_company_id select-area" style="width: 595px;">..</div>`**. Please check if the company ids are present under this div; if yes please write code to click on this element first **(Don't use the Select class here, just click on the div element directly)**, to show the dropdown and then select the relevant company id.

Comment: can you try to write me code example please, it will help me allot since im new to this

Comment: Why not just use `document.getElementById('company_id')` I'm confused...

Comment: so how do I use document.getElementById('company_id')? i hoped to get some code help...

Answer (score -1):

Execute this script before you try to find the element; something like this. Hope this help

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(" document.getElementById('company_id').style.visibility = 'visible'; ");
```

Comment: what is your driver implementation ? Are you using FirefoxDriver or ?? The sample given is based on Java using FirefoxDriver.

Comment: i use firefox driver, but with scala....anyway if i do driver.executeScript it dosent know executeScript @Alan M

Comment: look at this   [](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium)  search for "Executing JavaScript" in the page   `val result1 = executeScript("return document.title;")`

Comment: You don't want to do this. Don't force the element visible with javascript, interact with it just as a user would.

Comment: In this if the element get visible when the mouse is move into it this will sort the issue.